# How to properly re-order POST array coming from HTML?

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

Considering I have an array like this:

```
array:3 [▼
  "description" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "serv1"
    1 => "serv2"
  ]
  "quantity" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
  ]
  "cost" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "100"
    1 => "200"
  ]
]
```

Coming from a HTML form that looks like this:

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input 
            type="text" 
            name="service[description][]" 
            class="form-control" 
        />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input 
            type="text" 
            name="service[quantity][]" 
            class="form-control"
        />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input 
            type="text" 
            name="service[cost][]" 
            class="form-control" 
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I fix the array in such a way that the result is like this:

```
[
    ["description" => "serv1", "quantity" => "1", "cost" => "100"],
    ["description" => "serv2", "quantity" => "2", "cost" => "200"],
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop the arrays first subarray and use array_column.
Use array_combine and array_keys to get the keys correct.

```
foreach($_POST["description"] as $key => $val){
    $new[] = array_combine(array_keys($_POST),array_column($_POST, $key));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is an option - rebuild your markup to:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input 
            type="text" 
            name="service[0][description]" 
            class="form-control" 
        />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input 
            type="text" 
            name="service[0][quantity]" 
            class="form-control"
        />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input 
            type="text" 
            name="service[0][cost]" 
            class="form-control" 
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice **explicit** index in `name` attribute.

With this naming of `input`s your POST array will be already structured as you need and no server side rebuilding is required.

Comment: That's is an option in my current setup. Is there some alternative?

Comment: Alternative to __what__?

Comment: There's another answer, use it.

Comment: This is the way to do it, no need to reorder fields in the backend if you can fix the form in the frontend.